# What's the flaw in this derivative logic?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know this derivative:
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin{\theta}) = \cos{\theta}$$
I'm trying to find:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin{2x})$$
Why can't I do this:
$$Let\space \theta = 2x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin{2x})=\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin{\theta})=\cos{\theta}=\cos{2x}$$
I know it's wrong, and that I can use the chain rule to get $2\cos{2x}$, but where does the reasoning above go wrong exactly?

Comment: In short, you computed $\frac{d}{d(2x)}$ and you wanted $\frac{d}{dx}$.  To salvage this, you need the chain rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\theta =2x$, we get that $d\theta = 2 \, dx$. Hence you have to use the chain rule for differentiation.

So the calculations become, on using chain rule (marked in red):
 $$\boxed{\frac{d}{dx}(\sin{2x})=\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin{\theta})\color{red}{\cdot \frac{d\theta}{dx}}=\cos{\theta}\color{red}{\cdot 2}=\color{red}{2}\cos{2x}}$$

---

**Where you went wrong**:

Well, this is what you have done:

> $$Let\space \theta = 2x$$
>   $$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin{2x})=\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin{\theta})=\cos{\theta}=\cos{2x}$$

The mistake is in the 1st equality of the second line.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin{2x}) \color{red}{\not}=\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin{\theta})$$

Actually, you should correct this to, via proper substitution:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin{2x}) =\frac{d}{d(\frac{\theta}{\color{red}{2}})}(\sin{\theta})$$

since you have used the substitution:
$$\theta = 2x \implies d\theta = 2 \, dx$$

Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Edited successfully.

Answer (score 4):

You've mixed up your variables.

It's true that $${d\over dx}(\sin \color{blue}{2x})={d\over dx}(\sin\color{blue}{\theta}),$$ since $\theta=2x$ and all we've done is replaced one with the other (you're always allowed to replace a thing with, well, itself!). However, ${d\over dx}$ and ${d\over d\theta}$ are not the same, and this means you're in trouble when you claim $${d\over d\color{red}{x}}(\sin 2x)={d\over d\color{red}{\theta}}(\sin\theta).$$

---

Note that your original version and the new version of the question are making the same mistake, but in different places:

- Originally you wrote "${d\over dx}(\sin2x)={d\over dx}(\sin\theta)\color{red}{=}\cos(\theta);$" the first equality is true, but the second is false, since the two variables in ${d\over d\color{red}{x}}(\sin\color{red}{\theta})$ aren't the same.
- In the edited version "${d\over dx}(\sin2x)\color{red}{=}{d\over d\theta}(\sin\theta)=\cos(\theta),$" the second equality is true but the first is false, since $\sin 2x=\sin\theta$ but ${d\over d\color{red}{x}}$ is not the same as ${d\over d\color{red}{\theta}}$.

Answer (score 0):

You substituted $\theta=2x$ in the “numerator” $d \sin(2x)$ but not in the “denominator” $dx=d(\theta/2)=\frac{d\theta}{2}$. If you had done that you would have obtained the valid result.

That means you scaled the function in the “numerator” but left the $x$-axis unchaged.